# Missing kernel driver for VirtualBox on OpenSuse Tumbleweed

Tags: virtualbox, opensuse

I just installed a fresh OpenSuse Tumbleweed and installed "virtualbox, kernel-source" via yast. Added the normal user to the vboxusers group. Rebooted. And now I am getting the following error when trying to install a guest vm (also an OpenSuse):

```
linux-4tur:~ # ls -lah /sbin/vboxconfig
ls: cannot access '/sbin/vboxconfig': No such file or directory
linux-4tur:~ # ls -lah /sbin/ | grep -i vbox
linux-4tur:~ # 
linux-4tur:~ # ls -lah /dev/vboxdrv
ls: cannot access '/dev/vboxdrv': No such file or directory
linux-4tur:~ # 
linux-4tur:~ # modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.12-1-default
linux-4tur:~ #
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Does `zypper search virtualbox` still show it as installed? Also, can you find the vboxconfig executable with this command? `whereis vboxconfig`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. had to just reinstall ("update unconditionally" in Yast GUI) all virtualbox packages and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps at the moment of install yast gave you a warning?
Try install kernel-dev and reinstall virtualbox.

Try download and install manually the rpm from virtualbox site.

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case, the vboxconfig binary was present, but it was not marked as executable.  Marking it as executable and manually running it once fixed the issue for me.

```
# whereis vboxconfig
vboxconfig: /sbin/vboxconfig

# /sbin/vboxconfig
-bash: /sbin/vboxconfig: Permission denied

# ls -l /sbin/vboxconfig
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1334 Jun 21 12:12 /sbin/vboxconfig

# chmod +x /sbin/vboxconfig 

# /sbin/vboxconfig
Installing all required packages...
Building kernel modules...
Kernel modules built correctly. They will now be installed.
insmod /lib/modules/4.11.6-1-default/misc/vboxdrv.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.11.6-1-default/misc/vboxnetflt.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.11.6-1-default/misc/vboxnetadp.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.11.6-1-default/misc/vboxpci.ko 
Kernel modules are installed and loaded.
```